# Unable to get force:inputField or force:outputField to render inside other markup in Lightning Component when used in Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I've created a Lightning component to view key details for the Account and Contact lookups from a Case, like so:

[image]

The problem is, I have been unable to get field content to render when  using the `<force:inputField/>` or `<force:outputField/>` components when I place them inside the markup to style them as cards. I've used `<ui:outputText/>` as a workaround, but that means I don't get any of the built-in behaviors I would get with the `<force:*Field/>` components -- like Lightning styling, which means I have to manually do it using SLDS.

This displays the contact name as expected:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" controller="LightningCaseTestController">
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
  <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
  <aura:attribute name="contact" type="Contact" default="{sobjectType: 'Contact'}"/>

  <force:outputField value="{!v.contact.Name}"/>
  <force:inputField value="{!v.contact.Name}"/>

</aura:component>
```

This does not:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" controller="LightningCaseTestController">
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
  <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
  <aura:attribute name="contact" type="Contact" default="{sobjectType: 'Contact'}"/>

  <article>
    <force:outputField value="{!v.contact.Name}"/>
    <force:inputField value="{!v.contact.Name}"/>
  </article>

</aura:component>
```

Basically, it appears that as soon as *any* markup is placed around the `<force:*Field/>` tags -- even just a `<div>` -- they no longer render. Examples in Trailhead and other places all seem to use `<ui:outputText/>` or `<ui:input*/>`.

This seems like a lot of extra manual work. Am I missing something?

**Update:** it only fails when the component is included in a Lightning page -- such as the record detail page -- from Lightning App Builder. If I add it to a simple Lightning app, it works:

```
<aura:application >
    <c:LightningCaseTest recordId="SOMECASEID" />
</aura:application>
```

So it appears to be a bug?

Comment: sounds like a bug to me .Is it only happening inside the App builder or even if you view inside a simple lightning app?

Comment: Good call. I added the component to a simple Lightning app and it displays the content as expected. I'll update the question. That seems like a pretty big bug though!

Comment: It's a big  bug in builder !Huge .Did you tweet to someone or @askforce ?

Comment: I'm about to - I updated the question with additional details, now to go tweet at people.

Comment: How about using createComponent method to dynamically inject it .Sometimes it does make difference :)

Comment: Having the same issue in community builder too, i placed a lightning component inside the tab and when i go back to the tab the inputfields disappear.Does anyone have any info on how to fix it.
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just heard from Farhan Tahir, the product manager for Aura. He's confirmed that it is in fact a bug (W-3342864).

UPDATE: the bug's been nevered. PM guidance is to "use lightning namespaced components. `force:inputField` should be replaced with `lightning:inputField` (or even better with `lightning-input-field`, which is the LWC version)."

Comment: @shanonsans - Do you now if there's a link to this bug on the Known Issues Site? It would be good to be able to get to it directly, if possible.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be (that I can find)

Comment: Thanks @shannonsans. I was going crazy until I came across your post. *sigh*

Comment: Its a pretty big bug!! Six months later and it is still present. Did anyone find if it was on the path to be fixed?

Comment: Here's the known issue: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008gDzQAI

Answer (score 3):

As of Summer 17, here's the work around we're using:

```
<!-- component setup -->
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onInit}"/>
<aura:attribute name="newContractLine" type="Contract_Line__c" default="{'sobjectType': 'Contract_Line__c'}" />
<!-- end component setup -->

<!-- workaround for form fields below -->
<force:outputField aura:id="contractType" value="{!v.newContractLine.Type__c}" class="slds-hidden" />
<!-- end workaround -->

<!-- contract line form -->
<lightning:layout horizontalAlign="spread" multipleRows="true">

    <!-- type -->
    <lightning:layoutItem size="6" class="slds-p-horizontal--small">
        <ui:outputText class="slds-form-element--label" value="Type"/>
        <force:inputField aura:id="typeInput" value="{!v.newContractLine.Type__c}"/>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
    <!-- end type -->

</lightning:layout>
<!-- end contract line form -->
```

Comment: It works ... randomly. Reloading the page is a hit or miss. One year later, and this problem is not yet fixed ...

Answer (score 0):

I just found a weird work around for this:

```
<aura:attribute name="contact" type="Contact" default="{sobjectType: 'Contact'}"/>
<aura:attribute name="dummmyContact" type="Contact" default="{sobjectType: 'Contact'}"/>
<force:inputField value="{!v.dummmyContact.Name}" class="slds-hide"/>
<article>
    <force:outputField value="{!v.contact.Name}"/>
    <force:inputField value="{!v.contact.Name}"/>
</article>
```

By having one inputField at the top level (where we've confirmed that it can render), it seems to pull in the dependencies needed for the rest of the `force:` components to work.

Comment: This used to work until Spring 17. Starting with Summer 17 (v40) we cannot get the field to show anymore...