# force:inputField is not working in lightning experience

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I am creating LSDS modal to create a Task so I have an attribute of "Task" in component and using  to bind the fields of Task.
When I run lightning component using Lightning Application then it shows the task fields as Input but when I add my component in Lightning Experience by putting component on Home component then its showing Blank area not the fields as input.

```
<aura:attribute name="newTask" type="Task" description="new Task Object" default="{'sobjectType':'Task','TaskSubtype':'Task', 'Subject':'Call'}" access="GLOBAL"/>
<div class="wk_static">    
    <div role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aura:id="Modalbox" aria-labelledby="header43" class="slds-modal ">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">         
            <div class="slds-modal__header">                    
                <h2 id="header43" class="slds-text-heading--small" style="margin:0">Log A Call</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--small">
                <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">                        
                    <div class="slds-size--1-of-2">
                        <div class="slds-form-element">
                            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="subject">Subject</label>
                            <div class="slds-form-element__control">

                                <force:inputField aura:id="subject" value="{!v.newTask.Subject}"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <force:inputField aura:id="subject" value="{!v.newTask.WhoId}"/>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__footer">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onclick="{!c.removecssAndSave}" style="height: 30px;">Save</button>
                <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" onclick="{!c.removecss}" style="height: 30px;">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-backdrop " aura:id="MB-Back"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Have the same problem.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, since the marked answer refers to the Known Issue W-3342864 which is not accessible anymore (assumption: it's fixed) and you can't find it via search: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_index?keywords=force%3AinputField - Either it's the same issue again, or it was wrongly closed by Salesforce or it's something else. Not easy to say duplicate or not, even if it sounds similar

Answer (score 0):

Put the first div of your component as:

```
<div class="slds">
```

Comment: Thanks for response but unfortunately that's not working

Comment: can you share the whole component markup?

Answer (score 0):

There is an important thing to note when using force:inputField.  It will only work if it is directly under the aura:component tag.  There is a workaround for this though.

First, this knowledge article.
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008gDzQAI

And a workaround solution here: [Unable to get force:inputField or force:outputField to render inside other markup in Lightning Component when used in Lightning Experience](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/139668/unable-to-get-forceinputfield-or-forceoutputfield-to-render-inside-other-marku)

In case that link quits working.. Here is the workaround that Charles Naccio posted that he was using as of Summer '17.  I have used this type of workaround myself and I can confirm it does work.

```
<!-- component setup -->
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onInit}"/>
<aura:attribute name="newContractLine" type="Contract_Line__c" default="{'sobjectType': 'Contract_Line__c'}" />
<!-- end component setup -->

<!-- workaround for form fields below -->
<force:outputField aura:id="contractType" value="{!v.newContractLine.Type__c}" class="slds-hidden" />
<!-- end workaround -->

<!-- contract line form -->
<lightning:layout horizontalAlign="spread" multipleRows="true">

    <!-- type -->
    <lightning:layoutItem size="6" class="slds-p-horizontal--small">
        <ui:outputText class="slds-form-element--label" value="Type"/>
        <force:inputField aura:id="typeInput" value="{!v.newContractLine.Type__c}"/>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
    <!-- end type -->

</lightning:layout>
<!-- end contract line form -->
```