# How to render Address fields in Lightning components?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, address, forceinputfield

Is there any way to display an address field such as Account.MailingAddress on a custom Lightning component? I am overriding the New Account button with a custom Lightning component and I want to let users take advantage of the built-in Search Address feature as well as the State/Country picklists.

Comment: Mailingaddress is realted to contact AFAIK. What is stopping you from querying compound fields like select id,name,BillingStreet,Billingcity,BillingPostalCode from apex controller and showing on the component ?

Comment: I don't believe there is any out of the box solution for what you're looking for. You'd likely have to spin it up yourself using the individual fields Rao mentioned.

Comment: @Rao I am overriding the New Account button, so there's nothing to query for. Regardless, I can display regular text inputs, but I want to utilize the built-in Google Address Search functionality.

Comment: Maps and Location Settings are not available in Development org, so I cannot validate the autocompletion feature. I assume you are using force:inputField. In my org I can use         <force:inputField value="{!v.acc.BillingAddress}"/>
 and I see the billing address fields, do you get the autocompletion when you choose this method?

Comment: @Rao I am able to display them using force:inputField, however the generated compound fields have no labels and the State/Country picklists are not even showing up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got a response from SFDC R&D and there is a confirmed bug with address fields in Lightning components:

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000EAi2

Answer (score 1):

There is an important thing to note when using force:inputField.  It will only work if it is directly under the aura:component tag.  There is a workaround for this though.

First, this knowledge article.
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008gDzQAI

And a workaround solution here: [Unable to get force:inputField or force:outputField to render inside other markup in Lightning Component when used in Lightning Experience](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/139668/unable-to-get-forceinputfield-or-forceoutputfield-to-render-inside-other-marku)

In case that link quits working.. Here is the workaround that Charles Naccio posted that he was using as of Summer '17.  I have used this type of workaround myself and I can confirm it does work, though I have not tried it with the Mailing Address fields.

```
<!-- component setup -->
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onInit}"/>
<aura:attribute name="newContractLine" type="Contract_Line__c" default="{'sobjectType': 'Contract_Line__c'}" />
<!-- end component setup -->

<!-- workaround for form fields below -->
<force:outputField aura:id="contractType" value="{!v.newContractLine.Type__c}" class="slds-hidden" />
<!-- end workaround -->

<!-- contract line form -->
<lightning:layout horizontalAlign="spread" multipleRows="true">

    <!-- type -->
    <lightning:layoutItem size="6" class="slds-p-horizontal--small">
        <ui:outputText class="slds-form-element--label" value="Type"/>
        <force:inputField aura:id="typeInput" value="{!v.newContractLine.Type__c}"/>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
    <!-- end type -->

</lightning:layout>
<!-- end contract line form -->
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately when I use force:inputField I don't get the compound field labels, nor the State/Country picklists.

Comment: I have found picklist fields in general to not play well out of the box.  I wrote my own picklist component that pulls the describe for the field and populates the values dynamically.  It is reusable and works with multipicklists as well.